# How to fix scale Key-framing issue

Tags: video, premiere, adobe, keyframes, scale

I have been facing an issue with my Premiere Pro for a while now and no matter how hard I tried to find a solution, I never managed to find something that will fix my specific problem so that is why I came here and am asking for your help...

Here goes the problem,

I want to use the scaling option to create that basic effect of an image slowly zooming in/out over time but whenever I create two keyframes with a different scale value, the image just stays stuck on the bigger value even though it hasn't reached the keyframe yet and the scale value is slowly increasing/decreasing in the Effect Controls panel. To be more clear, here is a [quick video](https://youtu.be/Hkwm6Bdijd4) of me doing it.

Now, another thing that I noticed happening is that when I create motion on any other layer (doesn't necessarily have to be scaling motion) and try to do the scaling effect on the background image, the scaling effect reacts in some way, but it seems like it is interconnected with the keyframes of the other layer and follows them.

I really can't find the words to explain this phenomenon so [here is a video](https://youtu.be/suBrisNkqME) of it happening...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you machine might just be too slow to live render the effects. The red bar on your timeline is an indicator of that. Try selecting the clip in the timeline after you add the scale keys, then from the menu bar choose `Sequence > Render Selection`. After that renders out, the red bar in the timeline should change to green, and you should be able to play the preview video.

If rendering each effect before preview isn't an option, or is just too slow for you, you could also try changing the playback resolution in the Program monitor. That's the small fly-out menu under the main preview area that currently says `Full`. You can change that to `1/2` or `1/4` and it can significantly improve the live render capability of your machine. Everything will look more pixelated during preview playback, but it won't affect the final exports. 
[image]